# Android 3d Translates

Tags: android, 3d, translate, cube

I'm just starting to learn android programming and I want to ask you good people out there if there is a  way to achieve the CSS3 Translates in android. I am aware of the TranslateY and TranslateX functions in android but I don't see any translateZ. I'm actually trying to create a 360 panorama application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use method [glTranslatef](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#glTranslatef%28float,%20float,%20float%29) to move the viewpoint. Take a look on example [code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/development/samples/GlobalTime/src/com/android/globaltime/GlobalTime.java) on how glTranslatef is done here.